# how to aggregate pandas Series values based on predicate statement?

Tags: pandas

In R, it is easy to aggregate values and apply a function (in this case, `sum`)

```
> example <- c(a1=1,a2=2,b1=3,b2=4)
> example # this is the vector (equivalent to Series)
a1 a2 b1 b2 
 1  2  3  4 
> grepl("^a",names(example)) #predicate statement
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
> sum(example[grep("^a",names(example))]) #combined into one statement
[1] 3
```

The way I can think of doing this in pandas is to use a list comprehension rather than any vectorized pandas function:

```
In [55]: example = pd.Series({'a1':1,'a2':2,'b1':3,'b2':4})

In [56]: example
Out[56]: 
a1    1
a2    2
b1    3
b2    4
dtype: int64

In [63]: sum([example[x] for x in example.index if re.search('^a',x)])
Out[63]: 3
```

Is there any equivalent of the vectorized approach in pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pandas v0.12.0 you can convert the `Index` to a `Series` and search for the string using `str.contains`.

```
In [12]: s[s.index.to_series().str.contains('^a')].sum()
Out[12]: 3
```

In v0.13.0 use the `Series.filter` method:

```
In [6]: s = Series([1,2,3,4], index=['a1','a2','b1','b2'])

In [7]: s.filter(regex='^a')
Out[7]:
a1    1
a2    2
dtype: int64

In [8]: s.filter(regex='^a').sum()
Out[8]: 3
```

**NOTE:** The behavior of `filter` is untested in pandas git master, so I would use it with caution for now. There's [an open issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4324) to address this.

Comment: I wonder if str methods should be available directly for Index.

Comment: @AndyHayden I forgot that the `NDFrame.filter` method will work in 0.13!

Comment: boom! If I hadn't already +1d, I would again. That's how to do it!

Answer (score 3):

You can use groupby, which can apply a function to the index values (in this case looking at the first element):

```
In [11]: example.groupby(lambda x: x[0]).sum()
Out[11]:
a    3
b    7
dtype: int64

In [12]: example.groupby(lambda x: x[0]).sum()['a']
Out[12]: 3
```

Comment: +1 I always forget that you can pass a callable to `groupby`.

Comment: Very elegant, but I guess `groupby` would require more computation than necessary...

Comment: @crippledlambda rather than guess, you should always test (e.g. with `%timeit`), you may be surprised. Though in this case filter is *more* elegant!

Comment: That is true about using `%timeit`, but I was thinking in the general case and it seems that computing necessary statistics is undesirable. `groupby` is as elegant though.